# How to get push/remote notification when app in foreground in xamarin.ios native app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have implemented APNS push notification in Xamarin.ios native app and its work fine when app in background or kill state. 
We have unable to get notification in foreground state. How to solve this? 
Can any one suggest how to implement c# code for this

userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center willPresentNotification

Xamarin.ios native app . Please help/guide.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vsmac#handling-foreground-app-notifications).

You can call:

```
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge);

in userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center willPresentNotification
```

Default is `UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None` when on foreground which usually is normal because you don't want to show a push notif in when the app is in foreground unless your app requires it.

Comment: Can you tell me C# example for this in detail or any reference to implement it.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vsmac#handling-foreground-app-notifications)

take a look here it should help you implent it in c#. Basicly you need to implement a new user notification delegate and assign it to the center. UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate (); in onFinishedLaunch